# Why do I get a 500 Internal Server Error on Ubuntu but it works on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, django, apache2

I'm getting the following error in my apache log file when trying to create and download a pdf from an apache2 server running on ubuntu.  Running exactly the same programs on my raspberry pi is fine so I've clearly got something set up incorrectly giving django an issue but I cannot figure it out.  Help would be most welcome.

> ```
> [Fri Apr 22 15:50:46.852155 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 22606] [remote 109.149.72.248:60966] mod_wsgi (pid=22606): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/zouz$
> [Fri Apr 22 15:50:46.852198 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 22606] [remote 109.149.72.248:60966] Traceback (most recent call last):
> [Fri Apr 22 15:50:46.852213 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 22606] [remote 109.149.72.248:60966]   File "/var/www/zouzoukos/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handler$
> [Fri Apr 22 15:50:46.852295 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 22606] [remote 109.149.72.248:60966]     start_response(force_str(status), response_headers)
> [Fri Apr 22 15:50:46.852310 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 22606] [remote 109.149.72.248:60966] ValueError: carriage return/line feed character present in header value
> ```

Comment: I know that it might be dumb, but, did you check the config files diferences?

Comment: Yep, I've gone through both virtual environments and ensured they're exactly the same

Comment: But they are not only the libraries on the virtual environments, what about the apache configuration files, environment variables?

Comment: I not sure how to check these.  Can you advise?

Comment: Folks, I'm really sorry but I worked out what was wrong and it was that I had introduced a Greek character set into ReportLab for the version running on Ubuntu but not the version on RPi.  I've now sorted it by using utf-8 encoding.  I'm not sure how to now close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks, I'm really sorry but I worked out what was wrong and it was that I had introduced a Greek character set into ReportLab for the version running on Ubuntu but not the version on RPi.

I've now sorted it by using utf-8 encoding and will accept this answer and close this thread as soon as I can.